# Awk command with &&

Tags: awk, ansible

What I am trying to do is to use the awk with Ansible so that I can get the hostname and the vlume that are greater than 50%

I then can run the following to get the volume that has more than 50%

```
ansible-playbook pb-servermgmt_runcommand_goce.yml --extra-vars "hostlist=test01 command='df -hlT -x tmpfs -x devtmpfs -x iso9660 --total'" | awk '0+$6 >= 50 {print}'
        "/dev/mapper/rhel-root xfs    50G   35G   16G  70% /",
```

I can run the following to show me the server name

```
ansible-playbook pb-servermgmt_runcommand_goce.yml --extra-vars "hostlist=test01 command='df -hlT -x tmpfs -x devtmpfs -x iso9660 --total'" | awk '/ok/ {print}'
ok: [test01] => {
test01                 : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

I am wanting the following output

```
ok: [test01] => {
        "/dev/mapper/rhel-root xfs    50G   35G   16G  70% /",
```

I am looking at `&&` but I am just not getting the write syntax.
Any ideas ?

Comment: Isn't it already possible to get that information out of ansible facts via the `setup` module?

Comment: *`ansible_mounts`* don't provide tmpfs filesystems. Otherwise, you're right. *`ansible_mounts`* can be used to get the same info. The usage in percentage is missing, but this can be calculated. I added this code to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q: ***"Get the hostname and the volumes that use more than 50%"***

A: Instead of *awk* use the filter [*community.general.jc*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/docsite/filter_guide_conversions.html#converting-to-json) to parse the output of the command. Register the output of the command

```yaml
    - command: "{{ command }}"
      register: out
```

and declare the variable

```yaml
    my_df: "{{ out.stdout|community.general.jc('df') }}"
```

For example, the playbook below

```yaml
- hosts: "{{ hostlist }}"

  vars:

    my_df: "{{ out.stdout|community.general.jc('df') }}"

  tasks:

    - command: "{{ command }}"
      register: out

    - debug:
        var: my_df
```

---

gives (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e "hostlist=test01 command='df -hlT --total'"

PLAY [test01] *************************************************************************************

TASK [command] ************************************************************************************
changed: [test01]

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************
ok: [test01] => 
  my_df:
  - available: 1
    filesystem: devtmpfs
    mounted_on: /dev
    size: 1.9G
    type: devtmpfs
    use_percent: 0
    used: 0
  - available: 1
    filesystem: tmpfs
    mounted_on: /dev/shm
    size: 1.9G
    type: tmpfs
    use_percent: 0
    used: 0
  - available: 1
    filesystem: tmpfs
    mounted_on: /run
    size: 1.9G
    type: tmpfs
    use_percent: 11
    used: 193
  - available: 1
    filesystem: tmpfs
    mounted_on: /sys/fs/cgroup
    size: 1.9G
    type: tmpfs
    use_percent: 0
    used: 0
  - available: 2
    filesystem: /dev/mapper/cl-root
    mounted_on: /
    size: 18G
    type: xfs
    use_percent: 86
    used: 15
  - available: 820
    filesystem: /dev/sda2
    mounted_on: /boot
    size: 1014M
    type: xfs
    use_percent: 20
    used: 195
  - available: 592
    filesystem: /dev/sda1
    mounted_on: /boot/efi
    size: 599M
    type: vfat
    use_percent: 2
    used: 7
  - available: 374
    filesystem: tmpfs
    mounted_on: /run/user/1000
    size: 374M
    type: tmpfs
    use_percent: 0
    used: 0
  - available: 12
    filesystem: total
    mounted_on: '-'
    size: 27G
    type: '-'
    use_percent: 58
    used: 16
...
```

---

Then, you can use the list *my_df* and [select](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.select) or [reject](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.rejectattr) what you want. See [Jinja tests](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#list-of-builtin-tests). For example, select all filesystems of type *xfs* which use more than 50%

```yaml
    my_df_xfs_50: "{{ my_df|selectattr('type', '==', 'xfs')|
                            selectattr('use_percent', '>', 50)}}"
```

, or select the filesystem */dev/mapper/cl-root*

```yaml
    my_df_root: "{{ my_df|selectattr('filesystem', '==', '/dev/mapper/cl-root') }}"
```

In this example, both give the same results

```yaml
  my_df_xfs_50:
  - available: 2
    filesystem: /dev/mapper/cl-root
    mounted_on: /
    size: 18G
    type: xfs
    use_percent: 86
    used: 15
```

```yaml
  my_df_root:
  - available: 2
    filesystem: /dev/mapper/cl-root
    mounted_on: /
    size: 18G
    type: xfs
    use_percent: 86
    used: 15
```

**Write the hostname and the volumes that use more than 50%**

Declare the dictionary below

```yaml
  report: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts|
                   zip(ansible_play_hosts|
                       map('extract', hostvars, 'my_df_xfs_50'))) }}"
```

The debug

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_df_xfs_50: "{{ my_df_xfs_50 }}"
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {{ report }}
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
    test01:
    - available: 2
      filesystem: /dev/mapper/cl-root
      mounted_on: /
      size: 18G
      type: xfs
      use_percent: 86
      used: 15
```

See:

- [*run_once*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#running-on-a-single-machine-with-run-once)
- [*ansible_play_hosts*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#special-variables)
- [*extract*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-values-from-arrays-or-hashtables)

---

Q: ***"Isn't it already possible to get that information out of ansible facts via the setup module?"***

A: Yes. Instead of the command *df*, it's possible to use *ansible_mounts* collected by [*setup*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/setup_module.html#ansible-builtin-setup-module-gathers-facts-about-remote-hosts). This list doesn't provide the usage in percentage. Update the list with this attribute. Then, the playbook below

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: "{{ hostlist }}"

  vars:

    ansible_mounts_update_str: |
      {% for i in ansible_mounts %}
      {% set use_percent = 100 - i.size_available / i.size_total * 100 %}
      - {{ i|combine({'use_percent': use_percent|round|int}) }}
      {% endfor %}
    ansible_mounts_update: "{{ ansible_mounts_update_str|from_yaml }}"

    my_df_xfs_50: "{{ ansible_mounts_update|
                      selectattr('fstype', '==', 'xfs')|
                      selectattr('use_percent', '>', 50) }}"
    my_df_root: "{{ ansible_mounts_update|
                    selectattr('device', '==', '/dev/mapper/cl-root') }}"

    report: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts|
                     zip(ansible_play_hosts|
                         map('extract', hostvars, 'my_df_xfs_50'))) }}"

  tasks:

    - setup:
        gather_subset: mounts
    - debug:
        var: ansible_mounts
    - debug:
        var: ansible_mounts_update

    - debug:
        var: my_df_xfs_50
    - debug:
        var: my_df_root

    - set_fact:
        my_df_xfs_50: "{{ my_df_xfs_50 }}"
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {{ report }}
      run_once: true
```

gives (abridged) the same results

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e "hostlist=test01"

PLAY [test01] *************************************************************************************

TASK [setup] **************************************************************************************
ok: [test01]

...

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************
ok: [test01] => 
  my_df_xfs_50:
  - block_available: 617954
    block_size: 4096
    block_total: 4561408
    block_used: 3943454
    device: /dev/mapper/cl-root
    fstype: xfs
    inode_available: 4944209
    inode_total: 5351696
    inode_used: 407487
    mount: /
    options: rw,seclabel,relatime,attr2,inode64,logbufs=8,logbsize=32k,noquota
    size_available: 2531139584
    size_total: 18683527168
    use_percent: 86
    uuid: 2cb4d983-108f-40f3-bc22-8afae8edc80a

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************
ok: [test01] => 
  my_df_root:
  - block_available: 617954
    block_size: 4096
    block_total: 4561408
    block_used: 3943454
    device: /dev/mapper/cl-root
    fstype: xfs
    inode_available: 4944209
    inode_total: 5351696
    inode_used: 407487
    mount: /
    options: rw,seclabel,relatime,attr2,inode64,logbufs=8,logbsize=32k,noquota
    size_available: 2531139584
    size_total: 18683527168
    use_percent: 86
    uuid: 2cb4d983-108f-40f3-bc22-8afae8edc80a

TASK [set_fact] ***********************************************************************************
ok: [test01]

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************
ok: [test01] => 
  msg:
    test01:
    - block_available: 617954
      block_size: 4096
      block_total: 4561408
      block_used: 3943454
      device: /dev/mapper/cl-root
      fstype: xfs
      inode_available: 4944209
      inode_total: 5351696
      inode_used: 407487
      mount: /
      options: rw,seclabel,relatime,attr2,inode64,logbufs=8,logbsize=32k,noquota
      size_available: 2531139584
      size_total: 18683527168
      use_percent: 86
      uuid: 2cb4d983-108f-40f3-bc22-8afae8edc80a

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************
test01: ok=7    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```